# c# X509Certificate2 unsupported password chars

Tags: c#, openssl, x509certificate2, pkcs#12

We're using certificates as part of our authentication on multiple platforms like:

- linux(centos)
- windows
- ios
- osx
- android

The certificates are generated using openssl and as pass-phrase we use the user their password.

On linux everything works fine, but we're having issues on windows when the password has special characters like 'passwordé'

I'll put the code we use for changing the password to give a better understanding, as that's shorter and easier to understand.

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDPASS=password
NEWPASS=passwordé

openssl pkcs12 -nodes -in mycert -out mycert.tmp -passin pass:$OLDPASS -passout pass:$NEWPASS
openssl pkcs12 -nodes -export -in mycert.tmp -out mycert.final -passin pass:$NEWPASS -passout pass:$NEWPASS
```

The script was using env:NEWPASS and env:OLDPASS but changed it to make it simpler to track down the problem.

On windows, I'm always getting "The specified network password is not correct."
Keep in mind, removing the 'é' and it works fine again.

The code I'm using to open the certificate:

```
try {
   byte[] bytCert = <myCertificate>;
   objCert = new X509Certificate2(bytCert, pSecurePassword);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Incorrect password
}
```

I can't seem to find any documentation(or people having the same issue) on the net.
Does anyone know where I can find more info about this?

Does anyone know of a way around this problem?, the certificate is 100% valid, so I should be able to open it.

---

Edit:
I've tried openssl.net: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-net/
Strangely enough, same thing, works with 'password' and doesn't with 'passwordé', code used:

```
try {
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"/path/to/my/cert");
    OpenSSL.Core.BIO objBio = new OpenSSL.Core.BIO(fileBytes);
    OpenSSL.X509.PKCS12 objCert = new OpenSSL.X509.PKCS12(objBio, "passwordé");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like an encoding problem. Remember that `é` is not part of the ASCII space. While many Unix based systems use UTF-8 theses days, Windows uses [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or similar. I am not a C# expert, but you might need to check that your correctly encode/decode strings here so the format is valid.

Comment: in c# string is utf-16 if i remember correctly. Tried converting it to a utf8 string explicitly, didn't work. We might be having the same issue on ios devices, but not 100% sure it's confirmed yet.